# Why doesn't justifyContent: space-between work?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like `Text1Text2Text3Text4Text5Text6Text7` placed at the top and place the text with `justifyContent: 'space-between'`.

So I attempted but the texts are all placed at the to.

```
<div style={{display: 'flex-item', flex: 1, margin: 0, padding: 0}}>
    <div style={{float: 'left', flex: 1, display: 'flex-item'}}>
      <div>Place me below ul</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why is it that `justifyContent: 'space-between'` is not working? What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: It should be `justify-content` and `flex-direction` properties?

Comment: @DenisSheremet this is JSX and it works just like CSS, and currently `flexDirection` is working but `justifyContent` is not.

Comment: Please post the rendered result, as it should work but can't see the issue unless JSX render it wrong.

Comment: What happened here? Most of the original code (including the pertinent `justifyContent: 'space-between'` bit) and text is gone and a bunch of relevant tags removed for no apparent reason.

Comment: @BoltClock OP removed it 10 hours ago in an edit *shrug*

Comment: @JoKo I don't see `justifyContent` anywhere in the code presented here. Please [edit] your question to add the code you're having an issue with into the question. Also, please tell us what browser you're using, since [browser compatibility with flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) is not the best (IE11).

Answer (score 0):

In order to get space-between to work, you need to make sure the parent element has display:flex; and include all vendor prefixes.